# If get request unsuccessful, clear interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http, put

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:
I have a game that is running and the game periodically gets the state of the game. If a user logs out though, the game ends. But the problem is that the game still sends the put requests in the set interval.

I am looking for a condition, such as if put request is unsuccessful or something to clear the interval.

```
componentDidMount() {
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  this.getGameInfo(this.props.match.params.id);
}, 2000);
  if (this.getGameInfo(api get request) is unsuccessful(header not existent) { (pseudocode)
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: wow, smells self DDOS, try websockets!

Answer (score 1):

You can return a promise from getGameInfo and add a `.catch` callback function to clear the interval

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getGameInfo(this.props.match.params.id).catch(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: Cool thanks! I actually saw it wrong. It keeps sending get requests but the header does not exist anymore, and I am looking for a condition for that

Comment: you can add a try catch in your code, on catch return a promise.. and then use like mentioned above